Как работать с сервисом окон используя Ioc
Дошел до момента, когда ViewModel должна взаимодействовать с сервисом, чтобы он открыл окно, но при этом по идее наверно сервис не должен создавать окно), а только открывать и тут пока непонятки, что должен требовать Сервис в виде зависимости, подскажите пожалуйста куда двигаться.
Код VM, которая взаимодействует с сервисом
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public ICommand CreateBD { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        CreateBD = new Command(x =>
        {
            loginService.CreateBD();
        });
    }
}

Код сервиса, который должен открывать окно:
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    public LoginService()
    {
        
    }

    public void CreateBD()
    {

    }

Чтобы все работала все зарегистрировано, код:
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    _services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(_services);

    _serviceProvider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var loginWindow = _serviceProvider.GetService<LoginWindow>();
    loginWindow.Show();
}

void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<LoginWindow>();
    services.AddSingleton<LoginViewModel>();
    services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
}

Здесь я остановился, исходя из того, что сервис должен только открыть окно по требованию VM, то сервис не создает экземпляр окна, а только открывает.

IServiceProvider прокинуть нельзя как зависимость в сервис, чтобы дергать от туда зарегистрированное окно.
Само окно как зависимость тоже нельзя так как бизнес-логика не должна работать с view напрямую.
Создавать окно сервис не должен.
НО есть какая-то фабрика окон, которая наверно может прокинута как зависимость в сервис и уже она создает окно для сервиса, сервис лишь открывает его (непонятно будет при этом автоматически создана vm из контейнера для это окна, или придется дергать контейнер и сувать руками в datacontext окна).
Или же есть какие-то механизмы другие и я все не  правильно пишу)
Подскажите пожалуйста.


Окна в MVVM довольно сложная задача, ибо вам надо отделить UI от основного кода, да так, чтоб и VM и V не знали ничего друг про друга. Другими словами, у вас должен быть отдельный сервис, который знает про это все и по запросу инициализирует, связывает, открывает. Пример подобного можно посмотреть тут.

Понял, спасибоо

@EvgeniyZ правильно ли я понял, что этот сервис я регистрирую как зависимость, требую его в той ViewModel где, например есть команда, которая должна открыть окно и в этой же ViewModel регистрирую view и vm используя зависимость, и тут же открываю?

"Требую его" - нет, ибо вы должны делать все максимально абстрактным, где вы имеете интерфейс и его реализацию, это все регистрируете в контейнере, а затем просите интерфейс, а не реализацию. Грубо говоря: interface ITest { void Some(); } ... class SomeTest : ITest { public void Some(){ ... } } ... services.AddSingleton<ITest, SomeTest>();, далее public MainViewMode(ITest test) { test.Some(); }. Так вы можете в любой момент подменить реализацию во всем коде переписав всего 1 строку, либо вовсе, можете иметь несколько реализаций и просить их в разных местах. В остальном да, все так.

А понял так и хотел сделать)
